# WPF CustomControl overwriteable default style

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a question, about implementing default styles in a custom control in wpf.
I have writen my own IconButton control that puts two TextBlocks that are customizeable into a button control, which mostly works. The way this looks is like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}">
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    [...]>
                                </TextBlock>

                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                    [...]>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the corresponding MyButton.cs I have defined all the DependencyProperties refered to in both TextBlocks like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(IconButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

All of this works. I know I can have a default value in the DepedencyProperty (here string.Empty) and if I do so it is perfectly overwriteable by defining a new value when using "MyButton".
However obviously there's also regular styles for the button like Width and Height for example and for some reason I am not able to overwrite these, when I define them in my defined style. Besides that I was planning on defining the default values for my new dependency properties in the default style as well (simply for convinience), but it doesn't seem to work either.

Two things I have tried:
(1) Use a button style (obviously would only work for the DepdendencyProperties of the button not for my new ones)

```
<Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300"/>
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="24"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
   </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

or (2) define the default styles on TopLevel, i.e. just like another regular setter like I am using for the template (would work for my new DependencyProperties too):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
   <Setter Property="Template">...</Setter>
   <Setter Property="MinWidth">100</Setter>
</Style>
```

(2) seems like the better solution as in my opinion it is supposed to do everything I want, but it doesn't work at all. Neither of my style changes are applied.
(1) Is working, but obviously only for the buttons styles. However it is also not possible to overwrite these values, i.e., when I am using:

```
 <local:MyButton [...] MinWidth="100"/>
```

it does not overwrite the style which is what I would expect!

Please keep in mind I am a beginner and this is my very first custom control in WPF! Thanks for all advice.

Comment: If you are creating a Custom Control, then you need to set a default template key.
It is customary in WPF that this key is the element type.
Have you installed this key?
And did you create a theme with a default style?

Comment: Hey what do you mean with setting a default template key and installing that key? Isn't that what this line does: <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
Based on my understanding setting a key and using that for the style in my control, when I use it is not required here since this is supposed to be a default style.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution is the approach that has already been pointed out which is setting a default value when creating the DependencyProperty.
For other DependencyProperties that have been inherited it is possible to overwrite them in the the static constructor like so:

```
static MyButton()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    Button.FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(12D, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
    Button.MinWidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(120d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
    Button.MinHeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(24d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
}
```

i.e. you can easily access other DependencyProperties and overwrite their defaults.
The styles applied in the "Template" Property seem kind of hardcoded and I couldn't find a way to change them which is what I would  have prefered to do.

Any way: This is in C# code vs in XAML, but it does work and does everything that is desired.

Comment: Why `DefaultStyleKeyProperty` but `Button.FontSizeProperty`? In a derived Button class, `FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(...)` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Hey what do you mean with setting a default template key and installing that key?

When you create a Custom Control using Studio "Project" -> "Add New Item ..." -> "Custom Control (WPF)", a class template is inserted into the project.
In this template, Stuia always inserts a static constructor that defines the default key for your class:

```cs
    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }
```

Also, the "Themes" folder will be added to the Project, in which the "Generic.xaml" file will be stored.
This is a Resource Dictionary file that defines the default Templates for all Custom Controls created in the project.

Comment: Ahh yes, I have done exactly as you've pointed out. This is quite basic for making a custom control work, otherweise you wouldn't be able to add your own DependencyProperties to the CustomControl.

Comment: DependecyProperty has nothing to do with it.
We need a string specifying the default key for the type of your element: `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(...)`. Without this line, your element will default to a base type template. In your case, this is probably a Button.
For a more detailed answer, show the part of the code of your element containing the static constructor and the contents of the "Generic.xaml" file.